# How to handle production versioning with bundle in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, versioning, production

In angular 2 how to handle versioning of new changes for production, I have bundling file but when I changes in project it is not affected in live because browser has old bundle JS, so how to handle versioning for new bundle.

Comment: Are you using webpack or angular cli to create the bundle?